# About ORION instances deployment and infrastructure

Tags: fiware-orion

We are working in a `proyect` which aims at deploying and using several `ORION` instances. However, we have several general doubts about the `ORION` context broker:

- Is it a distributed `Pub/Sub infrastructure`?
- `ORION Context Broker` also support multiple broker instance deployment? If so, how does it establish inter-broker communication?

Simple broadcast is used as the other major `pub/sub` like `Redis`, `Mosquito`, and so on?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways of federating Orion Context Broker instances in a distributed architecture:

- ["Push" federation](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Context_Broker_Federation), in the sense notifyContext sent by one Orion instance are processed by other Orion instance (which, in sequence could trigger a notification to a 3rd level of Orion instance, and so on). Orion-to-Orion relationships are built in this case using subscribeContext.
- ["Pull" federation](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Registring_Context_Providers_and_request_forwarding), in which one Orion instance fowards a query/update to another Orion instance (which, in sequence could trigger a query/update forward to a 3rd level of Orion instance, and so on). Orion-to-Orion relationships are built in this case using the registerContext mechanism.

Note that an importand difference between two approaches is that in the "push" mode all the Orion instances update its local state, while in the "push" approach all the intermediate Orion instances acts as "proxy" without storing the data locally.